# Simulate float:top with css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

I have an ordered list of divs in a `<div id="mainContent">`. I want these divs to float top to bottom until the bottom of the page then if possible they move over a column and continue. If it can do nothing else it will have the items continue off the bottom of the page. The page should be allowed to be dynamically resized which means that if I cut off a column after resizing, it's elements should be appended to the previous column(s).

This is essentially what float:top would be if it existed. I should note that I will be using my site on mobile browsers so CSS3 is out. jQuery can be used though. I have tried masonry, but it doesn't enforce my ordering, it just acts like float: left, but will rearrange items of differing size to most efficiently use the available space (which is what the masonry homepage says it will do.

Is there anything that does this already? I would rather not have to custom script this if I can avoid it.

Comment: Check out CSS columns. Browser support is good for IE10 and up. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp

Comment: I appreciate the answer but my post clear states "CSS3 is out" and that is a CSS3 feature.

Comment: Mobile support for CSS3 is very, very good. The only browsers that can't use CSS3 are IE8 and IE9. Sorry, beyond that I have no other suggestions for you. I think this will have to be a custom jQuery script.

Comment: I have no idea where you got the notion that CSS3 isn't supported on the most popular (and nearly all) modern phones.

Comment: My client wants it to work on Windows Phone 7 browser. It doesn't support most CSS3 features (columns included). Please stop spamming my thread if you don't have an answer to MY question.

Comment: Not spamming. Trying to help! You didn't include the info that it must run on a Windows 7 Phone, so they didn't know. Please update your question.